# Why is Finally not called on my DownloadStringAsync Observable?

Tags: system.reactive

I'm using FromEventPattern and I want to be able to do some cleanup in the finally block of my observable.  Right now the finally block isn't being called.  It's my understanding I have to call OnCompleted...somewhere but not sure how to implement that.  Some code from my Silverlight program:

```
    public IObservable<string> StartDownload ( string uri )
    {
         WebClient wc = new WebClient();
         var o = Observable.FromEventPattern<DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs>( wc, "DownloadStringCompleted" )
                           .Select( s => s.EventArgs.Result );
         wc.DownloadStringAsync( new Uri( uri ) );

     return o;
    }



  public void TestRx ()
  {
     var anobs = StartDownload( "http://www.google.com" );

     anobs
       .Subscribe( stuff =>
       {
          // do stuff
       } );

     anobs
       .Finally( () =>
       {
          // not called?
       } );
  }
```

**UPDATE:**
Apparently my assumption that OnCompleted() would fix my problem was wrong.  I tried changing StartDownload to the following and Finally is still not called.  What is going on here?

```
  public IObservable<string> StartDownload ( string uri )
  {
     WebClient wc = new WebClient();

     var subject = new AsyncSubject<string>();

     wc.DownloadStringCompleted += ( sender, e ) => 
     {
        if ( e.Error != null )
           subject.OnError( e.Error );

        subject.OnNext( e.Result );
        subject.OnCompleted();
     };

     wc.DownloadStringAsync( new Uri( uri ) );         

     return subject;
  }
```

Comment: See my answer to a similar question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801505/using-rx-to-simplify-an-asynchronous-silverlight-web-service-request/3808990#3808990

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write your subscription code like this:

```
anobs
    .Finally(() =>
        {
        // will now be called. ;-)
        })
    .Subscribe(stuff =>
        {
        // do stuff
        });
```

Your `Finally` call returns a new observable that is "appended" to the `anobs` observable - it does nothing to actually modify the `anobs` observable at all. If you subscribe directly to `anobs` it doesn't know anything about the `Finally` call so it can't be called.

Comment: Ok that works! It should be noted that this only will work in combination with my updated StartDownload function with the OnCompleted call.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, that Rx operators are exactly like LINQ operators, in that they don't actually *do anything* until you do something to "ForEach" it (i.e. evaluate it). In Rx, `Subscribe` is like ForEach. Enigmativity is correct up here (but I wanted to explain a bit further as to *why* he's correct!)